# Cutefish on Debian won't load windowing environment

Tags: debian, grub

Well this is weird. After 20+ years of various distros, all the way back to RedHat before it was Fedora,  I guess I haven't seen it all.

Was installing Mozilla on Cutefish using the .deb Package installer when Cutefish (running from an ext drive) re-booted.  Grub bootloader came up, as always, I selected CuteFish, splash screen appeared - nothing out of the ordinary.
Instead of the normal Cutefish desktop a full screen terminal came up.
I logged on, had all my aliases available, history, everything, but no Desktop.
Below is the command history I tried to start the desktop:

759  sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
762  startx
763  sudo reboot
770  sudo tasksel
771  sudo apt-get install gdm3
773  sudo apt --fix-broken install
Nothing worked.

I copied the .xsession-error file to a thumb drive - all 375,00 lines.  Could not make sense of it.  If there is a way to extract the errors from only the last session, that might be helpful.

Now the weird part.
On a separate ext hard drive I have SUSE Linux 12, Desktop Edition.
Thought I would boot into SUSE Linux, copy my data from the CuteFish ext drive, and re-install CuteFish.
What do you know, SUSE Linux grub bootloader starts, I select SUSE Linux, and it also boots into a full screen terminal - but this time it's the recovery terminal, with a very limited set of commands, none of which are useful to me!!!
At least the CuteFish terminal was fully functional.

This does not look good.  (Both distros on the external hard drives were installed on a second computer as I'm scared to install GRUB on a working computer).

I have a third ext hard drive with Fedora.  That booted fine.
Mounted the CuteFish home directory, copied the all the files, scripts, backups over.
I am resigned to re-installing CuteFish, but if there a way - that is clear and explainable - to fix Cutefish so it boots like it used to I will devote at least an hour or two to try to recover. (I would, at least theoretically, be learning something.  Only takes half an hour to install Cutefish to an external hard drive).

Teachable moment, otherwise I will just go back and do the re-install.

Wuz gonna replace SUSE distro with POP-OS anyway, so no worries there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Instead of the normal Cutefish desktop a full screen terminal came up"